# Bcrypt hash giving warning 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression

Tags: javascript, async-await, bcrypt

```
const _create = async ({ email, pass }) => {
  try {
    const saltRounds = 10;
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds);
    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(pass, salt);
    ....
```

I have 2 files with similar code like above, one is working fine but other is giving warning **'await' has no effect on the type of this expression**

hash is returning a promise still the warning.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What in particular is "giving warning" here?

Comment: @AKX await on line 9 is showing given warning. I have edited the same.

Comment: Those functions don't return promises; see the docs how async is supposed to work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs#usage---async

Comment: @deceze if callback is not provided it does returns a promise, you can check the documentation. for synchronous there is a different function hashSync.

Comment: Hmm, true. Then the issue is that your IDE doesn't detect this properly either and issues this superfluous warning.

Comment: I got why the warning is thrown. It is only showing if i am having default parameters. In my function pass is default parameter